# AMD graphics drivers not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers

I need some help with my graphics driver. None of my games are working properly (the colors do not load properly and some of the objects are either missing or invisible). I have a Radeon 6870 and I'm confused by all the different types of drivers available for Ubuntu 16.04.